# Find the word in the grid

Tags: anagram

Find a ten letter word that can be formed by using the center letter twice and every other letter only once (it can be in any order, it doesn't have to snake around the grid).

```
F N H
D E A
O R B
```

Try another one:

```
T Y L
M A E
R N I
```

And the last one:

```
S M O
H C L
P A I
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the three are:

1.

> BEFOREHAND

2.

> ALIMENTARY

3.

> ACCOMPLISH